# How to get object(stdClass) from array

Tags: php

Given the array below, how do I get values of `object(stdClass)` such as `Pcv (campus Aalst)`, `Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Peeters Stefaan )`, and so on?

```
array(106) {
  [0]=>
 object(stdClass)#8 (45) {
    ["nid"]=>
    string(3) "199"
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "stageplaats"
    ["language"]=>
    string(2) "nl"
    ["uid"]=>
    string(2) "33"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created"]=>
    string(10) "1291279334"
    ["changed"]=>
    string(10) "1301323146"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["promote"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["moderate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["sticky"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tnid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["translate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["vid"]=>
    string(3) "206"
    ["revision_uid"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["title"]=>
    string(18) "Pcv (campus Aalst)"
    ["body"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["teaser"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["log"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["revision_timestamp"]=>
    string(10) "1301323146"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["nd_switch_bm"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "stage.revaki"
    ["picture"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["data"]=>
    string(72) "a:1:{s:13:"form_build_id";s:37:"form-f89b99e4a5249b192ff472579b826b00";}"
    ["field_stagedomein_audiologo"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_geneeskunde"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_lo"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_revaki"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "152"
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_verpleeg"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_status"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(14) "niet opgegeven"
      }
    }
    ["field_status_datum"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(15) "Europe/Brussels"
        ["timezone_db"]=>
        string(15) "Europe/Brussels"
        ["date_type"]=>
        string(4) "date"
      }
    }
    ["field_locatieview"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        string(3) "179"
      }
    }
    ["field_status_extra"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_status_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(6) "Actief"
      }
    }
    ["field_maxcapstud_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(2) "18"
      }
    }
    ["field_status_bevestigd_door"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_aanpers_stageplaats"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_extrainfo_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(37) "Capaciteit: 3 studenten alle periodes"
        ["format"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_percapaciteit_stageplaats"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_aanplaats_stageplaats"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_mentoren"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        string(3) "178"
      }
    }
["field_persoon_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["has_body"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#24 (45) {
    ["nid"]=>
    string(3) "211"
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "stageplaats"
    ["language"]=>
    string(2) "nl"
    ["uid"]=>
    string(2) "33"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created"]=>
    string(10) "1291281467"
    ["changed"]=>
    string(10) "1301323440"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["promote"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["moderate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["sticky"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tnid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["translate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["vid"]=>
    string(3) "218"
    ["revision_uid"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["title"]=>
    string(53) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Walravens Marc )"
    ["body"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["teaser"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["log"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["revision_timestamp"]=>
    string(10) "1301323440"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["nd_switch_bm"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "stage.revaki"
    ["picture"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["data"]=>
    string(72) "a:1:{s:13:"form_build_id";s:37:"form-f89b99e4a5249b192ff472579b826b00";}"
    ["field_stagedomein_audiologo"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_geneeskunde"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_lo"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_revaki"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "128"
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_verpleeg"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_status"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(14) "niet opgegeven"
      }
    }
    ["field_status_datum"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(15) "Europe/Brussels"
        ["timezone_db"]=>
        string(15) "Europe/Brussels"
        ["date_type"]=>
        string(4) "date"
      }
    }
    ["field_locatieview"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        string(3) "210"
      }
    }
    ["field_status_extra"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_status_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(6) "Actief"
      }
    }
    ["field_maxcapstud_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "4"
      }
    }
    ["field_status_bevestigd_door"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_aanpers_stageplaats"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_extrainfo_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(40) "Capaciteit: 1 student in periode 3 tem 6"
        ["format"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_percapaciteit_stageplaats"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_aanplaats_stageplaats"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_mentoren"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        string(3) "208"
      }
    }
    ["field_persoon_stagedomein"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["nid"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["has_body"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (45) {
    ["nid"]=>
    string(3) "217"
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "stageplaats"
    ["language"]=>
    string(2) "nl"
    ["uid"]=>
    string(2) "33"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created"]=>
    string(10) "1291281906"
    ["changed"]=>
    string(10) "1301323440"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["promote"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["moderate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["sticky"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tnid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["translate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["vid"]=>
    string(3) "224"
    ["revision_uid"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["title"]=>
    string(54) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Peeters Stefaan )"
    ["body"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["teaser"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["log"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["revision_timestamp"]=>
    string(10) "1301323440"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["nd_switch_bm"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "stage.revaki"
    ["picture"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["data"]=>
    string(72) "a:1:{s:13:"form_build_id";s:37:"form-f89b99e4a5249b192ff472579b826b00";}"
    ["field_stagedomein_audiologo"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_geneeskunde"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["field_stagedomein_lo"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The object is at the index 0 in the array, so you just access the property names from there

```
echo $theArray[0]->title;
```

For more information, please see the PHP manual's [Language Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php), especially

- the chapter on [Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and
- the chapter on [Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

Comment: Just found it. Thanks for your reply! $internshipsNaam[$keyInternships] = $valueInternship->title;