# how can i fetch data from this array (stdClass) php?

Tags: php, arrays, fetch, stdclass

how can i fetch data from this array (stdClass) php??

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [programs] => FireFox
            [version] => 4.00
            [type] => Browsers
            [description] => fdmkfdsf,sdfdsfdsfdsf
dfdsf
sd
f
dsf
ds
f
            [views] => 2
            [serial] => 434343-343434-3434-c
        )

)
```

when i tried to fetch it using foreach i got that error

```
#
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: views/results.php

Line Number: 2
```

How can i get the data of the program(e.g FireFox)??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get object(stdClass) from array.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491143/how-to-get-objectstdclass-from-array)

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = (your data);

echo $data[0]->programs;
```

Comment: i tried but it give me that A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/Serials.php

Line Number: 82

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this `$data` as array then you should change it as

```
$val =  json_decode(json_encode($data),true);//to convert stdClass object into array
echo"<pre>";
print_r($val)  //print the value of $val

echo $val['program'];  //Now you can use it as array in your code
```