# How to get object(stdClass) from array without the key?

Tags: php, performance, arrays, object

I looked at [How to get object(stdClass) from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491143/how-to-get-objectstdclass-from-array), but the answer didn't help me that much.

Here is a small example:

```
Array
(
    [25] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [name] => FOO
        )

    [27] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 27
            [name] => BAR
        )
)
```

***Note that the position is the same as the ID***, so I'm unable to know what is the exacly position, so I can't call

```
// since idk how many
$items = array_shift(array_values($array));
$items->name;
```

**nor**

```
// since idk the position
$items = array_shift(array_values($array[0]));
$items->name;
```

**The only solution that I could find was using a `foreach`**

```
foreach($array as $item){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($item->name);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

But this is my last resource, because I have 3 sub-arrays, not only `$array` but `$array['foo']` && `$array['bar']` && `$array['foobar']` and inside each is the structure above. Besides that, I need to test if the content exists, using `if(count($array['foo']) > 0`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  I don't understand the question.  "the position is the same as the ID", so you *do* know the position (`$items[25]->name`).

Comment: @RocketHazmat I want to read the array of objects (the $item->name for instance). But, Idk what's the position, the only way to read this is to read it in a foreach.

Comment: What do you mean "Idk what's the position"?  Does `$array[25]->name` not work?

Comment: @RocketHazmat `[25]` is a value unknown for me, it's dynamic.

Comment: What value are you using if not the index? This is why I believe the question is unclear. Do you want to make a function `get_item_by_nam("FOO")` that returns `$array[25]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I'm guessing you want to know what the keys (positions as you say) of the array are. Use array_keys for that:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

// $keys is now array(25, 27)
```