# PHP remove duplicated result in array inside an structure

Tags: php, arrays, structure

I making a language loop inside a structure that return the result in radio and i need to return the last select that user selected before inside this foreach ... in this code i get duplicated result the checked one and unchecked one.
How can I show the result checked without duplicated ?

```
<?php
    // to select the language that insert in table "x_language" for this user
    // the result is 1 in this case
    $usuario_id = $this->session->userdata('usuario_id');
    $usuario_id = $this->cake->get_current_language_to_user($usuario_id);
    // to get all languages from table "y_languages"
    $paises = $this->cake->get_paises();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($paises as $pais){
        // here i get to checked the "y_languages" -> "$pais->nome" that have the same result on "x_language"
        if($usuario_id['nome'] == $pais->nome){echo "<div class='radio iradio'><label><input type='radio' checked='checked' name='languageselected' value='".$pais->id_pais."'> ".$pais->nome."</label></div>"; }
        ++$i;
        echo "<div class='radio iradio'><label><input type='radio' name='languageselected' value='".$pais->id_pais."'> ".$pais->nome."</label></div>";

        if($i%17===0) { 
            echo "</div></div><div class='col-lg-2'><div class='radio iradio'>";
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this will work:

```
<?php
    // to select the language that insert in table "x_language" for this user
    // the result is 1 in this case
    $usuario_id = $this->session->userdata('usuario_id');
    $usuario_id = $this->cake->get_current_language_to_user($usuario_id);
    // to get all languages from table "y_languages"
    $paises = $this->cake->get_paises();
    $i = 0;
    //Getting unique from array
    $paises_unq = array_unique($paises[0]);
    foreach($paises_unq as $pais){
        // here i get to checked the "y_languages" -> "$pais->nome" that have the same result on "x_language"
        if($usuario_id['nome'] == $pais->nome){echo "<div class='radio iradio'><label><input type='radio' checked='checked' name='languageselected' value='".$pais->id_pais."'> ".$pais->nome."</label></div>"; }
        ++$i;
        echo "<div class='radio iradio'><label><input type='radio' name='languageselected' value='".$pais->id_pais."'> ".$pais->nome."</label></div>";

        if($i%17===0) { 
            echo "</div></div><div class='col-lg-2'><div class='radio iradio'>";
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: @Berney Stinson Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: this is result of `var_dump($paises);` array(99) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#27 (3) { ["id_pais"]=> string(1) "1" ["codigo"]=> string(5) "so_SO" ["nome"]=> string(11) "Af-Soomaali" }

Comment: There are no any repeated data I think

Comment: yes .. because the repeated data came from other array when i made if condition!!!! :) .. i think i have to merge the two arrays in one array and make after that array_unique. do you think is possible ? if yes how can be ?

Comment: See this for solution [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491143/how-to-get-objectstdclass-from-array)

Comment: same error Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: how to merge this 2 arrays and after that make array_unique?

Comment: Sorry, Which two arrays you are talking about?

Comment: its fine: 1) $usuario_id = $this->cake->get_current_language_to_user($usuario_id); 2) $paises = $this->cake->get_paises();